# Viewlsts.aspx page should be accessible to only people from specific group

Tags: permissions

I currently am working on SharePoint 2016, where I would like people from only specific group to view viewlsts.aspx page otherwise the people should be redirected to another page.

As I cannot inject script on viewlsts.aspx page, is there any other option on how can we manage on this.

I also don't to deploy any solution(wsp) for the same, need to achieve using out of the box or without wsp deployment.

Comment: This is not possible using any OOTB solution.

Comment: any custom script that I can place some where ?

Comment: Doing it with a script is just security through obscurity, can't you just set permissions on lists and libraries

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the `viewlsts.aspx` or its contents from the user should not be the approach for limiting access to lists or libraries. You should rather set appropriate permissions on list/library level to make only those lists accessible to users that they are allowed to open.

---

If the above is no solution in your case, you can still hide the content or redirect the user using a script. As you already stated, it is impossible to place such script using a Script Editor WebPart as the page itself is an application page and not a content page and not editable.

But you can still register a script to be executed using so-called User Custom Actions. Those can be registered either for an individual site or a whole site collection, but not on greater scope (i.e. not for a whole web application or the whole farm). See [the Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185004(v%3Doffice.14)) on how to register such a User Custom Action.

In the [Script Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.usercustomaction) attribute of the User Custom Action, you can then link to a JS file that you upload to a libary in SharePoint that every user can access (e.g. Style Library). The script then if effectively executed for every user and **has to check for itself** whether the user is on `viewlsts.aspx` by evaluating the URL, whether the user can access the page by evaluating e.g. group membership and then hide the content or redirect to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Only way is to inject the script via masterpage, you can create a json reference object to match against a particular page then redirect.
Sample code here:
https://gist.github.com/jonathanhotono/edbdbe11aeaad409ae04c33da88f5028

Comment: I would strongly discourage from editing/customizing the master page as it may impede future upgrades of the site. Rather use User Custom Actions, which of course can also be combined with a mechanism like in your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Classic mode, a User Custom Action is the best way to inject code into any specific page.

I would recommend making a JS file that you can selectively target a page with something like:

```
if(window.location.pathname.indexOf('viewlsts.aspx') > -1){
  <code here>
}
```

I highly recommend using this library ([$SP.ca](https://gist.github.com/iOnline247/db5d03c1fde98a749fbd)) to register a custom action.  see the Usage section commented on the bottom for the ability to copy and paste a template for what you're trying to do.

I created a plugin for the SP.js api that handles redirects if a site is in classic mode.  Feel free to use/tinker with it: [SP.Redirect](https://gist.github.com/BigRaj/acd834e94c5c8ad92f02d87e74ae4b4b)

Copy and paste it into the console, then run any of the usage scripts in the comment to see how it looks.  When testing, I recommend setting override to 'true' so you can click on the timer and stop the redirect from happening.

There are some other steps necessary to make it not trigger for certain groups.  Please see vgrem's solution for this, [SP.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup.js](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/8317710)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve your requirement is by implementing script in the master page.
If you want to apply custom css/js **only** on the site contents page, then first you have to identify the current page Url. Please find the below code for reference:

Please apply the below code in the head section of your Master Page

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
if(document.URL.toLowerCase().indexOf(‘viewlsts.aspx’) > -1)
{
//code for redirecting to another page 
or 

//code for dynamically loading your scripts

} 
</script>
```